# Hiding the variable value inside the state method

Tags: php, angularjs, angular, microservices

CODE USED:

```
/*Main from other page with URL*/
      .state("main/handler/location/userSso",{
             url:"/main/handler/:location/:",
             templateUrl:"component/common/main.html",
             controller: 'MainController'
    })
```

From one module to another module: https://example.com/#/main/handler/comp/99999300
Required :https://example.com/#/main/handler/comp/

> Do not want to pass UserID in URL.

```
.state("main/handler/location/userSso"  : users
```

so should be hidden from the view.

Comment: Is this question about angular or angularjs? Please edit your tags :)

Answer (score 0):

To hide value in url you have to define them in `params`  without `squash`

```
$stateProvider
  .state("main/handler/location/userSso",{
   url:"/main/handler?location?userId",
   templateUrl:"component/common/main.html", 
    controller: 'MainController',
    resolve: {},
    params: {
      location: {
        value: null 
       }
      userId: {
        value: null
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Is it possible to hide the userSso value from state method in angular js. 
$stateProvi
When ever I am clicking on some module it is coming as:
 der
  .state("main/handler/location/userSso",{
 url:"/main/handler/:location/:",
 templateUrl:"component/common/main.html", controller:
 'MainController' 
})
https://example.com/#/main/handler/comp/99999300
After some 5 to 10 seconds time it is coming to URL:
https://example.com/#/main/handler/comp